# How to get Url of a resource stored in database

Tags: mysql, sql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I have some files they are stored in mysql database as Blob(Binary large object). I want to create thumbnail for those files. But for thumbnail one must have url of the resource. I don't have the url because my data is stored in database. 
I know one solution that instead of storing data in mysql database I can store in AWS s3 bucket and from there I can get one public url and I can use that for creating thumbnail. 
Is there any way to get the url If the data is stored in database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as your data is stored in database, you will need to write it to disk first and then you can use its path for further use...

another approach would be to create thumbnail at the time of storage and copy it to a location, that way you can access the thumbnail whenever required. But you will need mapping of file vs its thumbnail...

Comment: I don't want to write data in my local because in real time data can be very large. So Is there is any other solution?

Comment: but you are writing the data to database the first time..
you can create a thumbnail at tht time...